# Plotly treemap data structure?

Tags: python, plotly, treemap

I hardly try to build a treemap with plotly.
The main difficulty I have is that the sub-categories don't fullfill the map. I think there is a problem in my data strucure. Thanks for any idea you could have

My source dataframe looks like this :

```
   id      parent   value   color
0   F      A1       20      0.298782
1   F      A2       10      0.030511
2   F      B1       35      0.562464
3   F      B2       45      0.778931
4   F      C1       30      0.308459
5   F      C2       46      0.505771
6   M      A1       24      0.242964
7   M      A2        6      0.604043
8   M      B1       24      0.279880
9   M      B2       57      0.269249
10  M      C1       82      0.914589
11  M      C2       61      0.827076
12  A1     Pat A    44      0.896741
13  A2     Pat B    16      0.112626
14  B2     Pat A    102     0.024187
15  B1     Pat B    59      0.462012
16  C1     Pat A    112     0.003501
17  C2     Pat B    107     0.614476
18  Pat A  total    258     0.150514
19  Pat B  total    182     0.698287
20  total  NaN      440     0.744805
```

I used the following code :

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Treemap(
    ids=df_all_trees['id'],
    labels=df_all_trees['id'],
    parents=df_all_trees['parent'],
    values=df_all_trees['value'],
    #branchvalues='total',
    marker=dict(
        colors=df_all_trees['value'],
        colorscale='RdBu',
        cmid=average_score),
    hovertemplate='<b>%{label} </b> <br> Sales: %{value}<br> Success rate: %{color:.2f}',
    name=''
    ))
fig.show()
```

and obtain something like this :

[image]

What I would like : something "fully mapped" like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be only the #branchvalues='total' to decoment. Hope nobody has wasted time with this.